# Como trabalhar com arquitetura multi tenancy?

Tags: php, mysql, arquitetura-de-software, multi-tenancy

Fui solicitado para desenvolver uma aplicação com arquitetura multi tenancy na linguagem PHP utilizando como banco de dados o MySQL.

Após ler vários materiais e posts pela internet, me surgiu uma dúvida. Como modelar a aplicação em si?

Tenho duas opções, sendo elas:

- **Aplicação e banco de dados compartilhados**

  Neste caso, teria apenas uma instância da aplicação e do banco de dados para todos os clientes.
- **Aplicação compartilhada e bancos de dados isolados**

  Neste caso, teria apenas uma instância da aplicação e cada cliente teria o seu banco de dados isolado.

A aplicação irá atender empresas (salões de beleza) que poderão ter somente a unidade sede e/ou a unidade sede e as unidades filiais. Todos os dois tipos serão multi-usuários e diversos módulos, alguns sendo: Cadastros de clientes, Cadastro de fornecedores, Cadastro de profissionais, Cadastro de Produtos e Serviços, Agenda, Controle de Estoque, Financeiro, Vendas e Compras.

Quem tem ou teve experiência com esse tipo de arquitetura multi tenancy, o que tem pra me aconselhar em relação ao uso do banco de dados? Pois a dúvida mesmo é: Utilizar o mesmo banco de dados para todos os clientes ou montar um novo banco de dados para cada novo cliente?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse texto.
http://www.die.ufpi.br/ercemapi2011/minicursos/MC4.pdf

Comment: @LeandroCurioso eu já li esse texto hoje e a partir dele que me surgiu essa dúvida. Obrigado!

Comment: Engraçado o seu post tendo em conta que eu estou neste momento a desenvolver uma plataforma nessa base. E mais engraçado é que é para essa área também com as mesmas tecnologias. Quanto a pergunta direi que depende muito do projeto... E da dimensão do mesmo.

Answer (score 7):

Eu trabalhei recentemente num projeto "multi-tenant". Não participei da decisão da arquitetura; apenas fiz manutenção e desenvolvimento com o projeto em estágio avançado.

Havia um banco de dados "central", que inclusive tinha o cadastro dos "tenants" em si. E, para cada "tenant", dentre os procedimentos no momento de sua inclusão, era criado um novo banco de dados.

A arquitetura me pareceu muito boa, e o código também era bem estruturado, bem coerente, sem confusão. A partir dessa minha breve interação com esse sistema, eu não recomendaria utilizar o mesmo banco de dados para todos os clientes. A separação "um banco de dados para cada cliente" deixa todo o desenvolvimento da aplicação muito mais simples.

Cada caso é um caso, mas fica a sugestão a partir do contato com uma aplicação real: um BD "central" e um BD para cada cliente é uma boa pedida.

P.S. - É claro que as ferramentas que você dispõe e a sua experiência com elas será importante para gerenciar essa complexidade. No caso, a aplicação estava em **Symfony 2** (que eu particularmente *não gosto*), porém imagino a mesma arquitetura realizada em **Laravel 4** (que eu particularmente *gosto*) sem grande dificuldade.

Answer (score 1):

### Utilizar o mesmo banco de dados para todos os clientes ou montar um novo banco de dados para cada novo cliente?

O que você deve analisar:

1 - Quantos usuários em potencial você espera atingir ?

É complicado estimar a quantidade com autoridade, mas acho
 que em termos de ordens de grandeza seria: Milhares? dezenas de milhares? mais?
 Se for uma grandeza alta de usuários seria aconselhável utilizar a abordagem compartilhada.

2 -  Quanto espaço de armazenamento que você espera de dados do usuarios média para ocupar?

Se você espera que estes usuários terão que armazenar grandes quantidades de dados a abordagem de banco de dados separado é provavelmente o melhor.

3 -  Quantos usuários simultâneos você espera suportar ?

Quanto maior o número, mais adequado seria o isolamento para atender  os requisitos.

4 - Você espera oferecer quaisquer serviços per-tenant de valor agregado, como backup per-tenant e restaurar backup?

Tais serviços são mais fáceis para oferecer através de uma abordagem mais isolado.

Claro que com o crescimento de algumas tecnologias o suporte/ armazenamento de informações pode ser facilmente questionado, mas em suma é isto!

### Analisando o seu problema:

A aplicação irá atender empresas (salões de beleza) que poderão ter somente

> a unidade sede e/ou a unidade sede e as unidades filiais. Todos os
>   dois tipos serão multi-usuários e diversos módulos, alguns sendo:
>   Cadastros de clientes, Cadastro de fornecedores, Cadastro de
>   profissionais, Cadastro de Produtos e Serviços, Agenda, Controle de
>   Estoque, Financeiro, Vendas e Compras.

Se você entendeu tudo que expliquei acima suas dúvidas serão as seguintes:

As empresas vão pedir serviço adicional como backup ou ter varias outras funcionalidades que não fazem sentido terem em outro salão de beleza (Relativo a empresas que vendem
um Serviço  e  customizações para cada cliente.)?

Então será recomendado o isolamento do banco de dados, caso contrario prefira o uso de uma base compartilhada.

Referencia: [How to create a multi-tenant database with shared table structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213006/how-to-create-a-multi-tenant-database-with-shared-table-structures)

Answer (score 0):

Bancos separados te dá mais segurança. Porém é mais fácil implementar uma abordagem utilizando o mesmo banco. 
Se puder, vá de bancos separados.

Comment: Se puder desenvolver mais a resposta seria excelenete.