# Uso compartilhado de bancos de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, cms, multi-tenancy

Um banco de dados MySQL pode ter uso compartilhado, ou seja, mais de um CMS pode usar o mesmo banco de dados, mudando-se somente o nome das tabelas?

Existem limites? Existem contraindicações? Estou perguntando porque estou estudando a AWS e estou pensando criar um BD no RDS e conectar a esse BD mais de um CMS.

Comment: Poder ate pode, mas não é o certo, primeiro ponto é que vai ficar algo muito grande e difícil de gerenciar, sem falar que pode haver confusões na hora que se esteja trabalhando em algum, o que pode ser um grande problema para integridade de dados.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Pode, e é correto fazer isso se você souber o que está fazendo. Tem até nome: chama-se *multi tenancy*. Se fizer direito e entender o que está fazendo fica mais fácil gerenciar a estrutura porque resolve em apenas um banco de dados tudo para todas instâncias de CMS.

Algumas pessoas se preocupam com performance, mas isso é ínfimo, quase imensurável, e se isso for um problema mesmo é algo de volume muito grande e provavelmente mais por causa da arquitetura geral e escolha de tecnologias erradas do que por ter escolhido ser *multi tenancy*.

Não há qualquer problema de integridade por causa disso, o banco de dados sabe gerenciar bem este tipo de situação. Você pode cometer algum erro? Claro que sim, mas pode cometer em qualquer situação. Pode cometer justamente por ter feito separado, e de fato vi muitos casos que a pessoa se perdeu por ter separado. Em qualquer opção você tem que fazer direito, não existe situação que pode errar e fica tudo bem.

Você sequer precisa trocar o nome das tabelas, pode usar as mesmas, depende do que quer.

Para tudo existem limites, mas de forma geral não precisa se preocupar muito com isto, é muito mais difícil arquitetar bem, modelar corretamente do que decidir sobre isto.

E para tudo tem contraindicações. É claro que existe alguma dificuldade em fazer desta forma, só não quer dizer que de outra forma não tenha dificuldades.

Note que não estou dizendo que deve usar, não sei o seu caso, estou dizendo que não é um problema usá-lo se for o mais adequado para você. A decisão não é simples e não pode ser baseada no que pessoas aleatórias te disseram na internet sem saber qual a real dificuldade que você tem e o que precisa resolver. Sem você saber disto não pode tomar a decisão correta.

Lembrando, se não souber o que está fazendo tudo pode dar errado e é melhor não fazer. Desenvolver software não é uma brincadeira de montar Lego, depende de conhecimento profundo e de diversas disciplinas.

Comment: Em primeiro lugar, foi muito bom saber que existe até termo técnico para esse tipo de uso de BD. Sinal que não é considerado gambiarra. Eu tenho feito muitos cursinhos na udemy e visto vídeos no Youtube. Também leio e frequento a DevMedia, que tem cursos de MySQL, que seria um desses conhecimentos necessários, certo? Que outras disciplinas seriam úteis? Na AWS, que BD, dos pequenos, recomendaria? Dizem que o Aurora é baseado no MySQL e tem melhor performance.  Será muito útil para mim poder ter um BD só, com limites, para mais de um CMS. Sabendo dos riscos, irei tomar cuidado.

Comment: Outro detalhe importante: se um determinado CMS bombar, poderei migrar os dados relativos a ele desse  BD Multi Tenancy para um outro BD? Ou seja, é possível criar uma estratégia de upgrade para o armazenamento de dados de um CMS de um Multi Tenancy para um BD exclusivo? Na AWS poderei fazer isso, se for possível, sem parar o serviço.

Comment: Gente, li várias perguntas dentro da tag "multitenancy" e creio que posso encerrar essa questão. A do Aurora-AWS creio que não está no escopo deste site. A pergunta de cima praticamente foi respondida aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15390/como-trabalhar-com-arquitetura-multi-tenancy